# How to store variables in arraylist in python

Tags: python, linux

I want to have something like

```
var1 = ('a','b','c')
var2 = ('a1','b1','c1')
var3 = ('a2','b2','c2')
var4 = ('a3','b4','c5')
var5 = ('a6','b6','c6')
```

How can i have all those in one variable var

I have a loop which will be saving each array but i want to have only one variable

Comment: use a list or a dict....where is the problem?

Comment: basically i want to have list of tuples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var = [var1, var2, var3, ('a3', 'b4', 'c5'), var5]
```

You could also copy var*i* in a loop, but that's very bad programming practice. Basically, you should construct a list upfront and not later from variable names. If you must do it, here's how:

```
var = [locals()['var' + str(i)] for i in range(6)]
```

This is the longer form of:

```
var = []
for i in range(6):
    var.append(locals()['var' + str(i)])
```

Comment: @Mahakaal basically `var = []` and then `var.append(('a', 'b', 'c'))` in the loop. Added a loop to the answer.

Comment: thanks buddy ,i found that and thats why i deleted my comment thinking u haven't read it. but thanks for that